# Spark Error : executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am working with following spark config

```
maxCores = 5
 driverMemory=2g
 executorMemory=17g
 executorInstances=100
```

Issue:
Out of 100 Executors, My job ends up with only 10 active executors, nonetheless enough memory is available. Even tried setting the executors to 250 only 10 remains active.All I am trying to do is loading a mulitpartition hive table  and doing df.count over it.

```
Please help me understanding the issue causing the executors kill
17/12/20 11:08:21 ERROR executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM
17/12/20 11:08:21 INFO storage.DiskBlockManager: Shutdown hook called
17/12/20 11:08:21 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
```

Not sure why yarn is killing my executors.

Comment: You should really look at the yarn logs using `yarn logs -applicationId` if available.

Comment: The executor is memory overhead, turn up the value of spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead or spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead or both. Let me know result. Also check if some other memory consuming job in background.

Comment: any solution? @Freeman

Answer (score 4):

I faced a similar issue where the investigation of the NodeManager-Logs lead me to the root cause.
You can access them via the Web-interface

```
nodeManagerAddress:PORT/logs
```

The **PORT** is specified in the *yarn-site.xml* under *yarn.nodemanager.webapp.address*. (default: **8042**)

**My Investigation-Workflow:**

1. Collect logs (yarn logs ... command)
2. Identify node and container (in these logs) emitting the *error*
3. Search the NodeManager-logs by Timestamp of the *error* for a root cause

Btw: you can access the aggregated collection (xml) of all configurations affecting a node at the same port with:

```
 nodeManagerAdress:PORT/conf
```

Comment: I checked nothing useful there.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this issue has more to do with the memory and the dynamic time allocations on executor/container levels. Make sure you can change the config params on executor/container level.

One of the ways you can resolve this issue is by changing this config value either on your spark-shell or spark job.

```
spark.dynamicAllocation.executorIdleTimeout
```

This thread has more detailed information on how to resolve this issue which worked for me:
https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21733

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, my spark job was using only 1 task node and killing the other provisioned nodes. This also happened when switching to EMR Serverless, my job was being run on only one "thread". Please see below as it fixed it for me:

```html
spark-submit \
--name KSSH-0.3 \
--class com.jiuye.KSSH     \
--master yarn     \
--deploy-mode cluster     \
--driver-memory 2g     \
--executor-memory 2g     \
--executor-cores   1   \
--num-executors 8 \
--jars $(echo /opt/software/spark2.1.1/spark_on_yarn/libs/*.jar | tr ' ' ',') \
--conf "spark.ui.showConsoleProgress=false" \
--conf "spark.yarn.am.memory=1024m" \
--conf "spark.yarn.am.memoryOverhead=1024m" \
--conf "spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead=1024m" \
--conf "spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=1024m" \
--conf "spark.yarn.am.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=300 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=50 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dcdh.version=5.12.0" \
--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=300 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=50 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dcdh.version=5.12.0" \
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=300 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=50 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dcdh.version=5.12.0" \
--conf "spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled=true" \
--conf "spark.streaming.kafka.maxRatePerPartition=1250" \
--conf "spark.locality.wait=1s" \
--conf "spark.shuffle.consolidateFiles=true" \

--conf "spark.executor.heartbeatInterval=360000" \
--conf "spark.network.timeout=420000" \

--conf "spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer" \
--conf "spark.hadoop.fs.hdfs.impl.disable.cache=true" \
/opt/software/spark2.1.1/spark_on_yarn/KSSH-0.3.jar
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33406485)