# Pyspark job possible resource limit issue

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I'm running a glue job in aws.  It basically runs pyspark code inside an aws glue job.  The job does some etl connecting to several ec2 instances.  It runs fine for a smaller number of instances but as I scale it up to a larger number it's failing and the final error log message is below.  I'm wondering is the code failing because of issues with one of the instances, or some part of my code, or is it a resource limitation caused by the default glue job settings?

I found a stackoverflow post mentioning SIGNAL TERM error that suggests the issue may have to do with memory or dynamic time allocations, could that be the problem and if so what parameters might I change to test that?

SO Post:
[Spark Error : executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47907561/spark-error-executor-coarsegrainedexecutorbackend-received-signal-term)

Error log:

```
2019-11-06 09:21:18,189 INFO  [Executor task launch worker for task 26635] memory.MemoryStore (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Block broadcast_477 stored as values in memory (estimated size 9.1 KB, free 2.8 GB)
2019-11-06 09:21:18,190 INFO  [dispatcher-event-loop-0] executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Got assigned task 26637
2019-11-06 09:21:18,191 INFO  [Executor task launch worker for task 26637] executor.Executor (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Running task 0.0 in stage 477.0 (TID 26637)
2019-11-06 09:21:18,191 INFO  [Executor task launch worker for task 26637] broadcast.TorrentBroadcast (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Started reading broadcast variable 479
2019-11-06 09:21:18,193 INFO  [Executor task launch worker for task 26637] memory.MemoryStore (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Block broadcast_479_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 5.1 KB, free 2.8 GB)
2019-11-06 09:21:18,194 INFO  [Executor task launch worker for task 26637] broadcast.TorrentBroadcast (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Reading broadcast variable 479 took 3 ms
2019-11-06 09:21:18,194 INFO  [Executor task launch worker for task 26637] memory.MemoryStore (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Block broadcast_479 stored as values in memory (estimated size 9.1 KB, free 2.8 GB)
2019-11-06 09:21:18,640 INFO  [Executor task launch worker for task 26629] codegen.CodeGenerator (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Code generated in 13.337938 ms
2019-11-06 09:21:18,841 INFO  [Executor task launch worker for task 26629] glue.JDBCRDD (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - closed connection
2019-11-06 09:21:18,884 INFO  [Executor task launch worker for task 26629] executor.Executor (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Finished task 0.0 in stage 469.0 (TID 26629). 1366 bytes result sent to driver
2019-11-06 09:21:19,156 INFO  [Executor task launch worker for task 26637] glue.JDBCRDD (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - closed connection
2019-11-06 09:21:19,230 INFO  [Executor task launch worker for task 26637] executor.Executor (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Finished task 0.0 in stage 477.0 (TID 26637). 1366 bytes result sent to driver
2019-11-06 09:21:23,308 INFO  [Executor task launch worker for task 26635] glue.JDBCRDD (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - closed connection
2019-11-06 09:21:23,790 INFO  [Executor task launch worker for task 26635] executor.Executor (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Finished task 0.0 in stage 475.0 (TID 26635). 1366 bytes result sent to driver
2019-11-06 09:21:23,940 INFO  [Executor task launch worker for task 26624] glue.JDBCRDD (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - closed connection
2019-11-06 09:21:24,279 INFO  [Executor task launch worker for task 26624] executor.Executor (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Finished task 0.0 in stage 464.0 (TID 26624). 1366 bytes result sent to driver
2019-11-06 09:22:26,134 ERROR [SIGTERM handler] executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend (SignalUtils.scala:apply$mcZ$sp(43)) - RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM
2019-11-06 09:22:26,139 INFO  [pool-7-thread-1] storage.DiskBlockManager (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Shutdown hook called
2019-11-06 09:22:26,139 INFO  [pool-7-thread-1] util.ShutdownHookManager (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)) - Shutdown hook called
End of LogType:stdout
```